# How do I do mixing of multiple dataframes in pandas got ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, merge

In Pandas using Anaconda3 Spyder I am running the following DataFrame Merge excercise:

I have two dataframes with structures below:

```
aur.columns
['Date','No','Clos'] 


bal.columns
['Date','No','Clos']
```

Both are Pandas DataFrames

I need to merge them into another data frame with same structure:

```
merg.columns
['Date','No','Clos']
```

The column common between them is 'Date' so the Merge should happen in this column:

```
aur
Date         No       Clos
11/12/2017   21       314
2/1/2016     12       766

bal
Date         No       Clos
1/1/15       4        3432
2/3/12       33       3123
```

The key thing to note in the data is that there might be some dates in the 'Date' column which may be there in bal but not there in aur and vice versa.
So you have to deal with missing keys in both the pandas dataframes  as well while merging them. NaN should be replaced with 0 while merging them.

When I use the following code this gives ValueError:

```
result = pd.merge(aur.Close, bal.Close, on='Date')

ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <cla    ss 
'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

So the merge is not happening and giving the error above.

Many Thanks in advance for your answers. May the best one win!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need merge `DataFrames` with 2 columns - `Close` and `Date`, so select these columns in both `DataFrames`  and then `merge`:

Also there are 2 format of datetimes as `strings`, so first convert them to `datetimes` for same `type`.

```
aur['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(aur['Date'])
bal['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(bal['Date'])

result = pd.merge(aur[['Close', 'Date']], bal[['Close', 'Date']], on='Date')
```

If use:

```
result = pd.merge(aur.Close, bal.Close, on='Date')
```

then try to merge with columns `Close` (`Series`) and get error.

Comment: let me try will post the result shortly

Comment: Yes it works This is the correct anwer. Thanks you so much for your help.

Comment: I was going to remind @PuneetMathur to accept the answer but I see he's accepted answers before... So he knows what he's doing (-:

Comment: @piRSquared - Thank you.

Comment: @jezrael the System does not allow your to now accept answers for 15 minutes had to wait to accept.